# simple key pressed event in python tkinter app

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm new to python and Tkinter. I'm looking for a small GUI app which contains a textbox on it and if any change occurs in the textbox content then it fires up an event for me to do something. I tried but failed to write such an event.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: By "textbox" do you mean the Entry widget or the Text widget?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use bind the [`<Key>` event](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm) to a callback like this:

```
import Tkinter as tk

class MyApp(object):
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.text = tk.Text(master)
        self.text.bind('<Key>', self.callback)
        self.text.pack()
        self.text.focus()

    def callback(self, event):
        print('{k!r}'.format(k = event.char))

root = tk.Tk()
app = MyApp(root)
root.mainloop()
```

(Like Steven Rumbalski, I'm not quite sure what you intended by 'textbox'. Happily, the above code will still work if you change `tk.Text` to `tk.Entry`.)

Comment: Thanks the above code is the exactly what i want,and sorry my GUI programming experience came from c# and there is only textboxes ,i don't understand what is the difference between entry and text? and my last question is how can get all text that is entered in this text/entry box? something like x=self.Text.get() thanks

Comment: A [tk.Text widget](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm) is a formatted text display which can include embedded images and windows, while an [tk.Entry widget](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm) is a single-line text box. To grab the text from a Text widget, use `x = self.text.get(1.0, tk.END)`.