# How to detect a key press in tkinter?

Tags: tkinter

I am making a game in python. I'm using Tkinter for the module
but how do you detect a key press for the movement.
here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
import keyboard
main = 1      
root = Tk()      
canvas = Canvas(root, width = 256, height = 415)      
canvas.pack()      
img = PhotoImage(file="Character.png")      
canvas.create_image(20,20, anchor=NW, image=img)
canvas.grid(row=3,column=9)

mainloop()
```

Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [simple key pressed event in python tkinter app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9421188/simple-key-pressed-event-in-python-tkinter-app)

Answer (score 1):

use the `bind_all` function. Assuming `tk` is your root window, you use this syntax:

```
tk.bind_all(sequence, function)
```

or, in real code:

```
def hi(x = None, y = None, event = None):
    print("Hello there. -Obi Wan Kenobi")

tk.bind_all("<h>", hi)
```

now, whenever you press the h button, "Hello there. -Obi Wan Kenobi" will be printed to the shell.

Tkinter also supports more advanced keyboard shortcuts.

For regular, one key shortcuts, you use the key, in between brackets, just like a HTML element. But to use other keys, like shift, you must use the same syntax, but with all the keys in the brackets, separated by hyphens. For example, for a shortcut for Control and f, use this syntax: `<Ctrl-f`. You will notice Control is `Ctrl`. For Shift, use `Shift`. for Alt,use `Alt`.